# Send a parameter from complete function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following sends values entered through a form to a php file:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: myPhpUrl,
    data: formValues,
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    success: function (data, textStatus)
    {     
        alert("Form sent successfully");           
    },
    complete: function () {
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Once the success function has alerted a success message, the complete function will reload the page.

I need to know from my PHP file that the page has been reloaded.

Is there any way  to send a parameter from the complete function to my PHP file? If not, any other approach to do so?

Comment: How about sending an AJAX call when the page (re)loads?  Or one before you reload (and then reload in that AJAX call's callback).

Comment: You could redirect to `window.location.href + '?someparameter'` and detect the `someparameter` in PHP to tell you the reload has occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
location.href=location.href+'?param='+my_param_value;
```